# Custom headers not showing with $_SERVER

Tags: php, ajax, header

Im trying to set a custom header like the code below:

```
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    beforeSend: function (request)
    {
        request.setRequestHeader("X_PJAX", 'true');
    },
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

The response is a 200 OK so i assume that it went ok.
But when i try getting the headers with `print_r($_SERVER)` it shows all the headers except the custom one i just set.

Has this something to do with Apache or with my code?

I've checked mod_headers and it is enabled.
Also tried to set the custom header with PHP and still no result and no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `apache_request_headers` read more about this here [APACHE REQUEST HEADERS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php)  `$_SERVER` contains Predefined values for the system and server , `apache_request_headers` will get your custom added headers.:

```
print_r(apache_request_headers());
```

Comment: I tried your code but still no result. You can see it on http://psarmidani.com. In the console you'll see the ajax request and the results are printed out

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani  Your site does not load at all.

Comment: true. i've exit the page to print out the result only

Comment: Oh nevermind i see the custom header in the console :D thnx for your answer. it helped me a lot !!

Comment: i just forgot that php load first :P

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani  if it helped , you should accept the answer. thanks